# Possible to print to PDF from Mac terminal?

Tags: macos, pdf, printing

Is it possible to take a file and print it to a PDF using nothing but terminal commands? I am guessing you would somehow make use of the lpr command, but I have yet to discover the correct syntax.

Comment: What sort of file? plain text?

Comment: @Daniel, I should've been more clear in my question: What sort of source file? -- My answer below will work for plain text files, but not for images.

Comment: @Doug I apologize, I actually misread the question.

Comment: @Daniel - What I'm really aiming for is something more graphically intensive, say HTML pages. Is this possible?

Comment: Your main problem probably is, that the viewer application is file format dependent. Make up your mind what format you want and you'll get specific answers.

Comment: @Daniel - "Make up my mind what format?" - I want to convert an HTML web page to PDF. That has been my intention all along. I have finally settled on wktmltopdf.

Comment: Did one of the responses answer your question? If not, what doesn't work or doesn't behave as intended?

Answer (score 18):

`lpr` is indeed the correct command. There's not much to it, just

```
lpr filename.pdf
```

should simply work, presuming that the default printer is set correctly. If not, you might have to do

```
lpr -P printername filename.pdf
```

Note that there's a man page -- "man lpr" if you need to see the content. Yes, the CUPS print daemon that OS X uses is already PDF aware.

Comment: Provided solution gives zero-size pdf on Yosemite.
Any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: Sorry for duplication. Provided solution gives zero-size pdf on Yosemite, when I'm trying to pring .pages document. RTF or txt are printed well. Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: lpr does not generate pdf files, so I am not sure I understand the comment. You cannot generate pdf files with lpr.

Comment: This does not answer the original question as it was how to 'print to pdf', not print a pdf.

Answer (score 6):

I know that I have seen something in a merely hidden system folder:

```
/Library/Scripts/Printing Scripts/Convert To PDF.scpt
```

I have created a new application from AppleScript but calling the script directly should work also.

EDIT:
actually you simply can call

```
/System/Library/Printers/Libraries/convert -f file.rtf -o file.pdf -j "application/pdf"
```

Comment: This answer is obsolete. Tested in OS X 10.9.5.

Comment: @4ae1e1 No, it isn't. Just that "convert" doesn't exist. It's a symlink to /usr/sbin/cupsfilter and cupsfilter will still work this way even on 10.13.6.

Answer (score 3):

1) The Open Source Word processor, [AbiWord](http://abisource.org), includes an option of converting between any formats it knows on the commandline, including PDF e.g.,

`abiword --to=pdf filename.html`

(It'll also handle, e.g., MS Word .doc files, .docx, .odt, .rtf, etc., both input and output.)

I know it's available for Mac, though I've never used it on a mac.

2) The `ebook-convert` command line program from [calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com) (on mac you need to follow the instructions [here](http://calibre-ebook.com/user_manual/cli/cli-index.html?highlight=tools) to get the commandline tools) is useful for many formats, too.

`ebook-convert filename.html filename.pdf`

It can handle .rtf and .odt input, and lots of ebook formats like .epub and .mobi.

3) [PrinceXML](http://www.princexml.com/) can be used on the commandline, and will convert HTML to PDF very beautifully.

4) There's [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/), which uses the webkit engine to convert HTML to PDF from the commandline. I've never tried it.

5) I can think of other methods using, e.g., ConTeXt or pdflatex, but they get more and more involved.

Comment: NB: AbiWord doesn't work on intel based Mac

Answer (score 2):

For plain text files, you can use `enscript` (comes with OS X) to generate a postscript file.

```
$ enscript -p ~/Desktop/profile.ps /etc/profile
[ 1 pages * 1 copy ] left in /Users/dharris/Desktop/profile.ps
```

OS X's Preview app can open (and convert) to PDF, or you can install [ps2pdf](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/doc/AFPL/6.50/Ps2pdf.htm) (I installed it via [macports](http://www.macports.org/)) and convert at the command line.

```
$ ps2pdf ~/Desktop/profile.ps ~/Desktop/profile.pdf
```

Comment: What if I wanted to do something more graphically intensive? Say, converting an HTML page to PDF from the terminal?

Comment: I know this is old, but PhantomJS can do this, and it does it very well.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use pandoc from http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/installing.html

With this command you would convert the html file to pdf:

```
pandoc -o output.pdf input.html
```

But note that pandoc uses LaTeX for the conversion, so you have to have a LaTeX system installed (http://www.tug.org/mactex/).

Pandoc can also convert to other formats like .odt, .docx and .epub

Answer (score 2):

"/System/Library/Printers/Libraries/./convert"
has been removed in later version of MacOS.

You can use sips now. AppleScript example:
do shell script "sips -s format pdf Filename.jpg --out Filename.pdf"

Nothing to install...

Answer (score 1):

For local web page files, you can try to use [Download URLs as PDF](http://automatorworld.com/archives/download-urls-as-pdfs/) Automator action. Download and install.

---

I had to start Automator in 32 bit mode:

[image]

---

Create an Automator *Application* that automatically *receives files and folders as input*, with this action as the only one. Save e.g. as `Save as PDF`.

Open the *Get Info* dialog of your application, and check *Open in 32-bit mode* also here. Double-click it once to make sure *Launch Services* knows the application.

---

You can use this application from the command line like this:

`osascript -e 'tell application "Save as PDF" to open { POSIX file "/path/to/file.html" as alias }'`

Of course, you can wrap this in a nice AppleScript `.scpt`, `bash` function, shell script, or what not.

---

This solution is actually pretty flexible. I was able to convert text files and HTML files, and the Automator action is also somewhat configurable.

Answer (score 1):

First get the printer name

```
lpstat -p
```

Then use the printer name (Canon1234 - for eg)

```
lp -d Canon1234 PathToDocument.pdf
```

Comment: Op is looking to print an arbitrary file to a pdf document, not print a pdf to a real printer.

Answer (score 0):

you can add pdf printer driver from using `pdf printer`

- first install `pdf printer` from the store then
- start `pdf printer`
- go to system preferences
- open printers and scanners
- click `+` button
- in printers list select `pdf printer`
- wait for a second
- then click    add
- set `pdf printer` as default printer then close...

open terminal 
then execute the command for print a file

```
lp /path/to/your/file/to/print.txt
```

Answer (score -1):

Actually it's a lot easier than that. You can just type on the command line `open *.pdf` and *Preview* will open with all the files there.  Weirdly though if you type `open *.pdf */*.pdf` you get two windows. In each you then have to go into the side bar, select one of the boxy formats (if there are a lot of files it opens by default in list format which doesn't work) type <kbd>CMD</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> to select all, then use the print-selected-pages command to get all of them.