# Mac: command line to convert pages document opened in Preview to PDF

Tags: command-line, pdf, iwork

Considering that there is no iWork installed and there is no "Preview.pdf" in the pages file package, how do I:

convert the pages document to PDF from command line?

I can open the pages document using Preview from command line using this command: "open -a Preview somedocument.pages"

But I don't know how to print that pages document to pdf from command line. I need to do it from command line not from the Preview GUI.

Many thanks before

Comment: Maybe you can follow the answerds to this question: http://superuser.com/questions/229418/possible-to-print-to-pdf-from-mac-terminal

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe Preview.app supports a variety of command line arguments; there is probably no way to do this directly from the command line.

You would likely be able to accomplish something along these lines via Automator, though.